# How to navigate to a special frame with prism for store apps in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, prism, navigationservice

I am relative new in the sector of App Developement for Windows RT and UWP and now I have a Windows 8.1 project where I want to use Prism. The app (a quiz game) consists of three pages and I want to implement a page header which is the same on all pages. I searched a lot but I don't found any solution how I could implement this with prism for store apps. Without Prism I could navigate to the mainpage and then call the function "myTargetFrame.Navigate(typeOf(secondPage));" but how could I do this in my scenario with prism, is that possible.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have you considered Template10 instead of Prism? http://aka.ms/template10 - or search Template 10 in Visual Studio Extension Manager and install the project templates. Navigation and framework are 99% identical to Prism.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it.

```
public sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
    {
        var masterPage = Container.Resolve<MasterPage>();
        masterPage.MyFrame = rootFrame;
        return masterPage;
    }

    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(Keys.MainPage, null);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

And then.

```
public sealed partial class MasterPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }

    public Frame MyFrame
    {
        get { return (Frame)GetValue(MyFrameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyFrameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyFrameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyFrame), typeof(Frame), 
            typeof(MasterPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And then.

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" Content="Header" />
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{x:Bind MyFrame, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Again, I recommend you take a look @ http://aka.ms/template10

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much Jerry! But I am working with a windows 8.1 project, will that also work? And template 10 is as far as i know only for Windows 10 projects (unfortunately). By the way I am really big fan of your courses on MVA, they are great! Entertaining an informative, I hope there will follow more and more ;-)

Comment: No, sorry, I gave you a Windows 10 answer. Did you watch my course on Prism for Windows 8? That combined with my answer might do it.

Comment: I am not sure if I watched it, but if not I would catch up this ;-) Thank you for your help - hopefully the next project is on windows 10.

Comment: Hello Jerry, is there any example avaliable where I can see how to do this with template 10? (Just a simple navigation header, no hamburger menu).